# How to get a value stored in a session inside a js function?

Tags: node.js, session

Here is js I use to store the value of my OTP inside the session:

```
app.use(session({
  secret:'mysecret'
});


app.post('/',(req,res)=>{
  var ss = req.session;
  ss.otp = req.body.otp;
});
```

Now I want to get this value inside my js function.

How can I do this?
Thank you.

Comment: which js function do you mean, you are allready accessing it in your post middleware? Which module do you use for creating the session?

Comment: Please specify inside which function do you want to get which value and what modules do you use here (what is `app`? what is `session`? show the code where you define them). I've made minor improvements to your initial post but it lacks some major bits.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand the question but is this what you are looking for?

```
app.post('/',(req,res)=>{
    var ss = req.session;
    ss.otp = req.body.otp; 
    myFunction(ss.opt)
});


function myFunction(opt){
    console.log('inside function with opt: ' + opt);
}
```

or are you trying to save it to the session for future use? in which case do this:

```
app.post('/',(req,res)=>{
    req.session.opt = req.body.otp;
});

//From a post
app.post('/newpost', (req,res)=>{
    if(req.session.opt){
        someFunction(req.session.opt);
    }
}

// From a get
app.get('/newroute', (req,res)=>{
    if(req.session.opt == 'somevalue'){
        console.log('opt exists')
    }else{
        //do something else
        res.redirect('/someredirect')
    }
}
```

Comment: yes i am storing my session for future use. What i want to do is first i saved the data inside my session from my server. Then i wanted to get this data into my html file where i have my function which calls on the click of a button.

Comment: Ok so the second example shows how to access the value from the session at a later time.

Comment: No i know this but i don't wants to get the value of the session on the same server page i want this value on my different HTML Page. I have a function there and from there i wants to check whether i have some data stored in my session or not

Comment: In one line i have stored the session value using node but i wants to retreive this value using Javascript or jquery.

Comment: The second example I posted would get you closer to what you are looking for. You cannot access the the session from the browser unless you pass the session values in the response or store portions of it in a cookie. I'd recommend following the example on this site, it will get you to where you want to be pretty quickly:https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/manage-session-using-node-js-express-4/

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong link originally above. I edited the comment with the correct link

Comment: yeah I thought so. I will go through this again thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments i get that you want to access the session data client side, which you cant, according to the docs (assuming you are using express-session):

https://github.com/expressjs/session#sessionoptions

> Note Session data is not saved in the cookie itself, just the session ID. Session data is stored server-side.

So my best guess is to just add a route

```
GET /me
```

where you return the user information you need.

Comment: Yeah you got me right this is exactly what i wanna do. So according to you first i have to store my session ID inside an cookie and then i can get my session value on client side using this same session ID which is inside the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

In Node JS you can obtain One Time Password (OTP) functionality by using a global variable instead of session variable.After generating OTP you can assign it to global variable and use it in any function. We can set expiry of that OTP by adding time out function after generation of OTP. For Example we can set time out to 120 seconds so after 120 sec that function will be executed and there we update the global otp variable. 
**Now in client side whatever otp we sent before will be invalid after 120 Seconds technically ;)**.

```js
//Node JS OTP Functionality
//OTP GENERATED FIRST TIME (Global Variable)
otp = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000).toString();
console.log("New OTP: "+otp);
//SENDING OTP TO CLIENT THROUGH EMAIL OR SMS and then...
//OTP Change after 120 Seconds
 setTimeout(function(){ otp = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000).toString();
    console.log("OTP CHANGED: "+otp+"(Previous Otp is Invalid)")}, 120000);
    
//120 Seconds timer...
    var timeleft = 120;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
  if(timeleft <= 0){
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Finished";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft + " seconds remaining";
  }
  timeleft -= 1;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
```